# Detecting multiple subfolders in Routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, routes

I want to match the following  URLs to the same controller in my Rails app

- /controller/folder1/folder2/
- /controller/folderA/folderB/somefile
- /controller/folderX/somefile

I currently can achieve the desired result if I limit the number of nested folders like so in my Routes.rb:

```
match '/controller(/:folder1)(/:folder2)(/:file)' => 'myspecial_controller#myaction'
```

Please note that the following does not work and an URL with multiple path components is not matched:

```
match '/controller/:full_path
```

I am wondering if there is some type of wildcard. So that I would ideally get an array of the path components that I can then assemble in the controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing)

```
match '/controller/*full_path'
```